# Ajax call succeeds, but has an undefined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please take a look at the [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9mwCG/38/)

Can anyone tell me why there is an "undefined" text appended to the div element `#tablearea` even though the Ajax request is successfully completed?

JSON:

```
[{"title":"A","nation":"Germany,Japan","city":"Hamburg,Toyko","Name":"John,Peter,Tom"},{"title":"B","nation":"Japan,Italy","city":"Toyko","Name":"Adam,Tom"},{"title":"C","nation":"Germany","city":"Berlin,Hamburg","Name":"Mary,Tom"}]
```

jQuery:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FRgDyl4%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
        success: function (data) {
            var item_html;
            item_html += "<table><thead><tr><th></th>";            
            $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {
                var title = item.title;
                item_html += '<th>'+title+'</th>';
            });
            item_html += "</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Germany</td>";
            $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {
                var nations = item.nation.replace(/ /g,'').split(",");
                console.log(nations);
                if ($.inArray('Germany', nations) < 0)
                {
                  item_html += "<td>No</td>";
                }else{
                  item_html += "<td>Yes</td>";
                }
                 });    

             item_html += "</tr><td>Berlin</td>";

             $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {
                var  citys = item.city.replace(/ /g,'').split(",");
                if ($.inArray('Berlin', citys) < 0)
                {
                  item_html += "<td>No</td>";
                }else
                {
                  item_html += "<td>Yes</td>";
                }

             });

              item_html += "</tr><td>Peter</td>";

             $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {
                var  names = item.Name.replace(/ /g,'').split(",");
                if ($.inArray('Peter', names) < 0)
                {
                  item_html += "<td>No</td>";
                }else
                {
                  item_html += "<td>Yes</td>";
                }

             });

           item_html += "</tr></tbody></table>";

           $('#tablearea').append(item_html);

        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tablearea"></div>
```

Returned Results:

```
<div id="tablearea">    
undefined
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Germany</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Berlin</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>No</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `var item_html = "";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to intialize `item_html` with `""` in the first place like so:

```
item_html = "";
```

if you just declare `item_html` without initializing it, it is undefined. appending a string to it leads to the behaviour of your code..

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUJ3d/) for for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try to declare item_html with value

```
var item_html ="";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the following statement completely.

```
var item_html;
```

It's bad procedure but still you can do it if you want.